# Image Not Loading in flutter android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I tried everything but nothing seems to work. **According to me, the path of the image is correct. (though I have attached an image for reference)**. This is the error I am getting -

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: start.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:225
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:668
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:651
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:504
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "start.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#2bd13(), name: "start.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

this is **pubspec.yaml*-

name: foodfast
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

splashscreen: ^1.3.5

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter:

uses-material-design: true

assets:
- assets/start.png

**sign_in.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('sign in'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
          child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(image: AssetImage('start.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          new Text('text below image')
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: reference for path of image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your path of image first i.e. **assets** and then add image name

```
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/start.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
```

Comment: It wasn't that intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the full path even if you have already given it in pubspec.yaml.

Hence, it should be `'assets/start.png'`

Answer (score 1):

Use full path like ***'assets/start.png'*** in your image path.

```
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/start.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path from

`AssetImage("/image/start.png")`
to

`AssetImage("./image/start.png")`

(`.` means go to the highest folder level)

This worked for me!